# PHP display cookies and remove suggested in browser

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, browser

How do I get this cookies code to display properly? Both in Google Chrome and Firefox I get a dropdown suggestion from the browser. I would like to only have my own php "setcookie" to display.

PHP:

**index.php:**

```
      <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control fill-bar" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email"
              value="<?php
              if(isset($_COOKIE["username"])) {
                if(isset($_POST["email"])) {
                  echo($_POST["email"]);
                }
              } ?>" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control fill-bar" id="passwd" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["password"])) { echo $_COOKIE["password"]; } ?>" required>
            </div>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="mr-1">Remember Me</p>
            <a href="reset-password.php" class="color-mwc-orange blue-hover">Forgot your password?</a>
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn d-inline btn-primary register_button mr-3 w-100" id="login" name="login" value="Login">

            <p class="text-center mt-3">No account yet? <a href="register.php" class="color-mwc-orange blue-hover">Register Here</a></p>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- end row -->
      </form>
```

**page-2.php:** (inside if isset login button clicked)

```
            if(!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
                setcookie ("email",$_POST["email"],time()+ 3600);
                setcookie ("password",$_POST["password"],time()+ 3600);
                echo "Cookies Set Successfuly";
            } else {
                setcookie("email","");
                setcookie("password","");
                echo "Cookies Not Set";
            }
```

Instead of my "setcookie", both Google and Firefox displayes these, I would like to have them not appear.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Try using `autocomplete="off"` on your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, add the `autocomplete` attribute to your inputs and set it to `off`, like the following:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control fill-bar" id="passwd" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["password"])) { echo $_COOKIE["password"]; } ?>" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

That should be enough to prevent autocomplete. However, [browsers are not required to follow that attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields). You can check which browsers currently comply with the `autocomplete` attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Browser_compatibility). In the case of a browser not respecting the `autocomplete` attribute, you could try using methods to mangle the input names (such as [jQuery plugins](https://github.com/terrylinooo/jquery.disableAutoFill) or by using PHP to generate random names and store those names in the user's session, and verify the form versus the session on submit).

Comment: somehow autocomplete off does not remove the suggested dropdown info

Comment: for some reason autocomplete="new-password" did it